# How to build CyanogenMod against HTC One X

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I've tried to build [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) against HTC One X by following the guide:

http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_endeavoru.

But this guide is kind of out of date, and I encountered some problems:

1. Cannot find the vendor info

   evans@host:~/android/system$ breakfast endeavoru
   including vendor/cm/vendorsetup.sh
   build/core/product_config.mk:238: *** _nic.PRODUCTS.[[device/htc/endeavoru/cm.mk]]: "vendor/htc/endeavoru/endeavoru-vendor.mk" does not exist.  Stop.
   Device endeavoru not found. Attempting to retrieve device repository from CyanogenMod Github (http://github.com/CyanogenMod).
   Found repository: android_device_htc_endeavoru
   Default revision: cm-10.2
   Checking branch info
   CyanogenMod/android_device_htc_endeavoru already exists
   Syncing repository to retrieve project.
   Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_device_htc_endeavoru
   Fetching projects: 100% (1/1), done.

   Repository synced!
   Looking for dependencies
   Done
   build/core/product_config.mk:238: *** _nic.PRODUCTS.[[device/htc/endeavoru/cm.mk]]: "vendor/htc/endeavoru/endeavoru-vendor.mk" does not exist.  Stop.

   ** Don't have a product spec for: 'cm_endeavoru'
   ** Do you have the right repo manifest?
2. There is no extract-files.sh any more.

So what should I do to extract proprietary files from my device?

I found there is a `copy-and-setup-makefiles.sh` , is it used to instead `extract-files.sh` ? How to use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to build CyanogenMod 12 (based on Android 5.0 Lollipop), you need to make a few changes to the build instructions for CyanogenMod 11 (based on Android 4.4.4 KitKat), which are (when this was written in January 2014), linked on the wiki.  Among the changes you'll need to do for Lollipop:

- First make sure that there is a cm-12.0 branch for your [device](https://github.com/cyanogenmod/android_device_htc_endeavoru/tree/cm-12.0) and [kernel](https://github.com/cyanogenmod/android_kernel_htc_endeavoru/tree/cm-12.0) repositories.  I see that for the endeavoru-- your device, the HTC One X-- this is the case.
- To initialize the repository, you'll want to replace cm-11.0 with cm-12.0 so that the init command will look something like:  `repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-12.0`
- CyanogenMod 12 is built with Java 7-- so replace `openjdk-6-jdk` and `openjdk-6-jre` with `openjdk-7-jdk` and `openjdk-7-jre`.  (The two versions can be installed concurrently.)
- CyanogenMod 12 does not have any "prebuilt" apps (previous versions had the rom-manager.apk and term.apk as prebuilt, but no longer), so you can skip the `get-prebuilts` step.

The build error you posted above seems to be due to missing files and the .mk makefiles that copy them to the $OUT directory for installation.  The files are generally moved from the stock installation into a `/vendor/manufacturer/device_codename` directory (such as `/vendor/htc/endeavoru`) to be installed back onto your device in CM12.  And the `extract-files.sh` script is generally the method by which these blobs are archived from an existing installation such as stock to your source code tree.  You can read more about it in the wiki section called **Extract proprietary blobs**.

You said there is no `extract-files.sh` script, but I do see one in the cm-12.0 device tree right [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_htc_endeavoru/blob/cm-12.0/extract-files.sh) (as well as a cm-11.0 one [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_htc_endeavoru/blob/cm-11.0/extract-files.sh)) in the `device/htc/endeavoru/extract-files.sh` path as expected.  So you might give it a shot again.

Good luck!